# Can I force Maven to package a jar despite compilation errors?

Tags: java, maven

So I run `maven package` to build my dependencies into a jar. However, I need Maven to ignore any compilation errors and package the jar regardless.

How would this be accomplished? My `pom.xml` is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <!-- Project specific stuff would be here... -->

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>wherever</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- etc... -->
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Searching through SO only showed me how to ignore compilation errors from unit testing. I simply want my package to be compiled despite any errors in the code.

---

**Edit:** People seem to be bashing on me. I've been doing Java for 5 years. I know you're not supposed to compile with errors. I know what it entails.

My boss programs with me. He specifically said, "I can compile with errors in Eclipse, so compile with errors in Maven." It's not because I am ignorant, or because I refuse to accept my mistakes. It is because that is what I was specifically ordered to do. I did not ask this question because I am incompetent as many of you would like to assume.

Hate on me all you want, just know that you are doing so unfairly.

Comment: That's a *really* bad idea. How do you expect your application to function with (presumably) *random* missing classes?

Comment: I don't. However, like many others on StackOverflow, I am told what I must do for my job. Sometimes that means doing the wrong thing. I tried convincing my boss this is a horrible idea. However, he won't budge. If it's not possible, then so be it.

Comment: If your code doesn't compile, then there is nothing to package...

Comment: (untested): The Eclipse compiler can 1) treat compilation errors as non-fatal (generating code that throws an exception and nothing else) and 2) be used by Maven as the java compiler.  See http://www.gabiaxel.com/2011/10/replacing-javac-with-eclipse-compiler.html and http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-using_batch_compiler.htm

Comment: sounds like you need a new job

Comment: Horrible idea and very easy to explain why as seen in previous comments .  If your boss just wants finished package then fine go fix compile errors otherwise tell him you are not done. Garbage in garbage out.

Comment: This answer describes how to use the Eclipse compiler from Maven and configuring it to treat errors as warnings: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24088623/incremental-java-compile-with-maven-like-eclipse-does

Comment: You say it is also possible to ignore compilation errors from unit tests. How is that done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [the exclude option to the compiler plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#excludes) to exclude the classes that have compile errors.

Answer (score 7):

Building on Top of @wings Answer

You can use the flag `failOnError=false` in your `pom`, too

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <failOnError>false</failOnError>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

or via command line

```
mvn package -Dmaven.compiler.failOnError=false
```

Answer (score 6):

Maybe this is what you want: 
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#failOnError

Set `failOnError=false` to ignore compilation errors.

Answer (score 1):

When you run maven package. That means maven will run all phases before "package" phase. Hence maven compile will be triggered for sure. And because of compilation error, maven will stop at "compile" phase.

To package  your project even with compilation error. I think you should use "maven assembly plugin" to package your depensencies ONLY and the phase of that plugin should be something before "compile". ex: "process-sources" or "process-resources".

By that way, before maven compiles your project's source code, you will have a bundle which includes all dependencies. Of course, maven will stop at the "compile" phase again. But you already have what you want.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just about the dependencies there's [`dependency:copy-dependencies`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html):

> Goal that copies the project dependencies from the repository to a defined location.

Use [`assembly:single`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/single-mojo.html) with a [user-defined](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html) [descriptor](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html) to create the JAR with the dependencies from the location defined above:

> Assemble an application bundle or distribution from an assembly descriptor.